# Update Database Using Dataadapter

Tags: c#, database, vb.net, sqlite

I have an SQLiteConnection, SQLiteDataAdapter, DataTable and a BindingSource in my code. I'm trying to save datagridview data to the database. Here's my code:

```
sqliteDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
sqliteDataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
```

However, I'm getting an error:

> Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

Do I have to define SelectCommand, UpdateCommand and DeleteCommand each time I want to save to the database? And how can I fix this?

Comment: The message is pretty obvious: that SQLite data adapter requires valid update statement in `UpdateCommand`. Can you show how your update query looks like?

Comment: I don't have an update query. I just want to dump datagridview content to database.

Comment: `sqliteDataAdapter.Update` tries to save changes if any `DataRow`s modified. Since you're not modifying anything (instead using something like 'bulk update'), consider other method than `DataAdapter.Update`.

Comment: Thank you for helping! I guess datagridview.EndEdit() won't work.

Comment: There's no such thing as "dumping DataGridView content to database. Your `DataTable` contains `DataRows`. Each of those rows is either unchanged of contains changes. Changes can be inserts, updates or deletes. If you want to insert rows then your data adapter needs its `InsertCommand` set. Likewise for updates and the `UpdateCommand` and deletes and the `DeleteCommand`. You can use a command builder in some cases or you can set them yourself as needed. You need to do some proper research on data access in VB.NET instead of chucking something together.

Comment: [Generating Commands with CommandBuilders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/generating-commands-with-commandbuilders) can help here. just add: `Dim cb As New SQLiteCommandBuilder(sqliteDataAdapter )`.

Comment: If you define the Adapter as class level object, you can define ALL the SQL command just one - the Adapter will remember them and even open the connection as needed.  MSDN has lots and lots or articles on the topic and there are many hundreds of similar questions here